# How to use switch case in Mongo shell script?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Am trying to update a document, which has companyid 123 and it has name "karun "  . If it doesn't have the name Karun, I am inserting it. Similarly how I can check for each of the other 10 names and update it or insert it.

Example:

```
 Do.collectionname.update(
   { "companyid": "123", "name": { $in: ["karun"] } },
   { $set: { "name": "karun", "age": 20, "weight": 50 } },
   { upsert:true }
 )
```

Comment: Note that as its tag wiki describes, the `shell` tag is principally for POSIX-flavored shells.

Comment: BTW, you say "the other 10 names", but the code sample doesn't imply you have any other names at all. Consider providing at least two or three to show a pattern of what you mean to do.